# ng-disabled with bootstrap dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like my textfield be disabled depending on the bootstrap dropdown value.
So I wrote this

Dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown">
<div ng-controller="dropDownCtrl">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown">
{{selectedItem}}<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-model="dropDown">
<li ng-repeat="a in subjects"><a ng-click="dropboxitemselected(a)">{{a}}</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

textfield

```
<div ng-controller="dropDownCtrl as ddc">
<label for="requester">Requester</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disabled="ddc.checker" ng-model="requester"  id="requester" placeholder="requester" />
</div>
```

and here's angular controller

```
app.controller('dropDownCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.subjects = ['Yes','No'];
this.checker=false;
$scope.selectedItem;

$scope.dropboxitemselected = function (item) {
  $scope.selectedItem = item;
  if($scope.selectedItem == "Yes") {
      this.checker=true;
      alert($scope.selectedItem);
    }
}
});
```

All of the above are in the same  tag. Alert tells me that function is called however textfield is still enabled. Can somebody tell my why ? Thanks!

Comment: Why is the `ng-controller` directive called on both? I think they both have their own instance, so their own values, which does not affect other parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each controller has its own scope, and each call to `ng-controller`, you get a new instance of the controller.

So the `checker` variable does not get shared between the two parts where you're specifying the controller.

You may test to see what I mean with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pguhf5s/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it works

```
app.controller('dropDownCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.subjects = ['Yes','No'];
$scope.checker=false;
$scope.selectedItem;

$scope.dropboxitemselected = function (item) {
  $scope.selectedItem = item;
  if($scope.selectedItem == "Yes") {
      $scope.checker=true;
      alert($scope.selectedItem);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a function that returns `checker` value and use it on the ng-disabled

```
$scope.disabledFunc = function () {
    return this.checker //I would use $scope.checker...
}
```

And then:

```
<div ng-controller="dropDownCtrl as ddc">
<label for="requester">Requester</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disabled="disabledFunc()" ng-model="requester"  id="requester" placeholder="requester" />
</div>
```

Anyway, why don't you use `$scope.checker` instead of `this.checker`? And then: `ng-disabled="checker"`

On the other hand, I suggest you to use angular routing to "link" controllers with their views. I think is the best practice.